# Angular test suite throwing Maximum Call Stack exceeded after running test suite several times

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a test suite with about 200 test in it. When I run the test suite 4-5 times I eventually get the error.

browser-source-map-support.js:111 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

At face value this would imply I have an infinite loop. However given that the test suite runs fine it's unlikely. So I disabled the vast majority of the test except one file, then duplicated the test a thousand time and tried again. This time the same error pops up but takes many more iteration before it appears (25+). Which leads me to believe there might be some memory leak somewhere.

I can reproduce this issue with any of the spec files. Leading me to believe they're all broken in the same way, or that it's my karma conf that's broken.

I thought variable leaking might be the issue, as described [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/941) but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Angular 10
Karma 6.3

karma.conf.js

```
const path = require("path");
const plugins = [
"karma-jasmine",
"karma-chrome-launcher",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma",
];

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
    plugins: plugins,
    client: {
    clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    jasmine: {
        random: true,
    },
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, "./coverage/portal"),
    reports: ["html", "lcovonly", "text-summary"],
    fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ["progress", "kjhtml"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["ChromeDebugging"],
    customLaunchers: {
    ChromeDebugging: {
        base: "Chrome",
        flags: ["--remote-debugging-port=9333"],
    },
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    files: [{ pattern: "./src/assets/**", watched: false, included: false, nocache: false, served: true }],
    proxies: {
    "/portal/": "/base/src/",
    },
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue this week after updating several karma and jasmine related dependencies in our project. What seems to have fixed it for me was to delete the `node_modules` folder and do a fresh `npm install`. If you did not try that yet, give it a shot, could have saved me hours of debugging and research...